# How web scrape data from this line .. there is no div and no class element I can't find.i want to extract data from that line??how

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<p> ==$0
  "1."the purpose of our lives is 
   to be happy." - "
   <strong>Dalai Lama</strong>
</P>
```

## there is many quotes like above form tags and I can't find locating elements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/  hey pls help me how to locate element for 150 quotes in URL

Comment: Which text you want to find please edit with expected output

Comment: 1. “The purpose of our lives is to be happy.” — Dalai Lama

2. “Life is what happens when you’re busy making other plans.” — John Lennon, open url inspect tools tell me find elements to webscraping  pls

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                 import requests                                                                                                                     URL = ("https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/")
web_page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, "html.parser")
quotes = []
result = soup.find('p')
print(result) #print all quotes in above url how pls explain me for doing one  quotes atleast and i am not geting tp print  all quotes?

Comment: @manoj check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    x = [x.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for x in soup.select(
        'span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p')]

    goal = [i for i in x if i[0].isdigit()]
    pp(goal)


main('https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/')
```

> Note, If you are using `Windows` machine, **DO NOT** forget to include *from_encoding=* equal to the encoding used by your sys.

Ref: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings

Otherwise:

```
print("\n".join(goal))
```

Comment: hey Tq, can u explain this code x = [x.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for x in soup.select(
        'span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p')]   and how to save all quotes to mysql database

Comment: @manoj for your other question, open a new question.

Comment: How did u find soup.select(
        'span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p')] in developer tools ..untill now I didn't get idea where did u find that I didn't get in developer tools which u find  element

Comment: @Demon That's called `CSS SELECTOR`

Comment: Yes,,but I didn't get in developer tools there is only paragraph tag and strong tag is there..

Comment: @Demon are you aware on how to accept an answer provided to you?

Comment: No.. I don't know

Comment: @Demon To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: U didn't explain me how that css selector did u find in developer tools ,,I didn't find  and j don't have such deep idea?

Comment: @Demon can you show me a screenshot showing that you are unable to locate the element ?

Comment: @ahmed american I hope here there is no option to share screenshot, So here open this link https://photos.app.goo.gl/jRCPpuxEx6PfHPoUA will u get screen shot, there is only i see p tag and strong tag..if anything is more  about to find that element which u find explain me or u show screen shot then i will get an idea because i am not too much deep in scraping finding elements.

Comment: @Demon `CSS SELECTOR` is not an element where you can find within HTML dom. `CSS` selectors is a kind of command which we target the element with it. you've to insert the following CSS `span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p` within `filter` box and press enter.

Comment: @ahmed American ok fine can u share best tutorial link for about web scraping deep to learn.