# My Sql error occured data too long in row

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

```
Code:

import mysql.connector as MYSQL
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/'
SQL = 'INSERT INTO quoteslist (id, Quotes) VALUES (%s,%s)'

CONFIG = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'Demon@',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'my_quotes',
    'charset': 'utf8mb4'
}
SELECT = 'span[data-parade-type="promoarea"] .figure_block ~ p'
GT = {'strip': True, 'separator': ' '}
with requests.Session() as session:
    web_page = session.get(URL)
    web_page.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text, "html.parser")
    quote = [(x.get_text(**GT)) for x in soup.select(SELECT)]
    with MYSQL.Connect(**CONFIG) as db:
        mycursor = db.cursor()
        for q in quote:
            idx = q.split()[0]
            if idx[0].isdigit():
                text = q[len(idx):].strip()
                params = (idx.replace('.', ''), text)
                mycursor.execute(SQL, params)
        db.commit()
```

Output error:

```
line 29, in <module>  mycursor.execute(SQL, params)
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'Quotes' at row 
1
```

I try to insert the data all 150  quotes in URL, getting error data too long in row 1.
I don't have such deep idea about that error. Can anyone tell me how to correct the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How web scrape data from this line .. there is no div and no class element I can't find.i want to extract data from that line??how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652697/how-web-scrape-data-from-this-line-there-is-no-div-and-no-class-element-i-can)

Comment: @ahmed american NO

Comment: is there a reason to post your question using different usernames ? in case if you've exceeded the limit. then you've to wait

Comment: @ahmed American Did u know which code went wrong , showing data too long in row 1  error?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a `VARCHAR(255)` type for `quoteslist.Quotes`, and encountering a line longer than 255 characters. In particular, you will notice that on the website you linked, in row number 59, the quote is longer than 275 characters. That just cannot fit into a `VARCHAR(255)` column, and this is what your database engine is complaining about.

The fact that it says the data is too long in "row 1" is irrelevant -- that just means that the problem is in the first row (out of 1) that you're attempting to `INSERT`. SQL allows you to insert multiple rows in a single command, and if any one of them doesn't work, they all fail to be added, which is why this message is useful.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (val VARCHAR(5));
INSERT INTO test VALUES ("123"), ("12345"), ("1234567");
-- Data too long for column 'val' at row 3
```

To actually solve this, you can upgrade your `Quotes` column [to a `TEXT` type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/text/), which fits 65535 bytes. If that's not enough, there's a choice of [`TEXT` and `BLOB` types](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/blob-and-text-data-types/) you can use, the biggest of which holds 4294967295 or 2**32-1 bytes -- you'll have a hard time exceeding that limit, but if you do, you will have to store the data across several columns.